# Permanently changing a node's contents in java

Tags: java, tree, nodes

Say i have a node that stores a `HashSet<String`> (hence it is an instance variable of that node). I have a getter method that allows me to retrieve that `HashSet`, but now I really need to update it. Is this possible? If not, what would be a good workaround?  I have implemented my Tree as such:

```
public class CTree implements Serializable {
    public CRoot initialCommit;

      public CTree(int id, CNode parent, HashSet<String> files) {   
           root = new CNode(id, parent, files, inheritedFiles);
      }

    public static class CNode implements Serializable {
       int nodeID;
       CNode parent;
       HashSet<String> toCommit;

    public CNode(int id, CNode parent, HashSet<String> files) { 
        nodeID = id;
        this.parent = parent;
        toCommit = files;

      }

         public HashSet<String> getFiles() {
             return this.toCommit;
         }  

          public CommitNode getParent() {
            return this.parent;
          }


         public int getID() {
           return this.nodeID;
          }
     }


}
```

Comment: Depends on how the node is defined. Please post an example.

Comment: updated with implementation :)

Comment: When you get the `HashSet`, you can do whatever you want on it.. What's the problem of updating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the node's `HashSet` you aren't getting a copy of the `HashSet`, you're getting a reference to the same object in the node.  So you can just update it and the contents of the Node will also be updated since they point to the same object.

You may be getting confused with returning a primitive.  In this case, the value is copied and modifying it has no effect on the original primitive.